# Android.Content.Res.Resources has only getObject<T>

Tags: xamarin.android

I need to reach my `string.xml` files from code in a Xamarin.Android project. So, basically I need to use the `getString()` method of `Resources` (as I have searched this very site), but there isn't any! Only `GetObject<T>` is here.

I'm going after it here:

```
Android.Content.Res.Resources.getString(...).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Res.Resources.GetString/p/System.Int32/), there *is* a `String GetString (Int32 id)` function. You need to get a `Resources` instance from the application context, using `getResources()`, then you can call the method.

Comment: Thank you for your help ^____^. I used it but that .getObject<T> is a completely different beast ^____^ ... needs two or three parameters...and is not what we commonly after. As I said, I only needed to use Application.Context.Resources. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes...this it .. but the easier way is to say: Application.Context.Resources.